# Configure QuickLook to open particular files

Tags: quicklook, quicklook-plugin

I'm wondering if there's a way to get QuickLook open up files it doesn't recognize.

For example, I'd like to be able to have QuickLook view .mailsignature files in the basic text viewer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to open them with [QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.com/qlstephen/) which opens all kinds of files that are plain text.

I am hesitant to recommend it since it will try to open every file for which you don't have another plugin as plain text which is not helpful. It has a blacklist but I found myself constantly adding things to said list which makes it kind of bothersome to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is close but it looks like that will only open files that don't have an extension, which is a bit limiting. Something like this that allows you to indicate which extensions to open would be perfect.

Comment: Have you tried it? The description is a bit misleading. I've had this version installed for about a week before tossing it due to said flaws. It did what I said.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Does have the drawbacks you mention but more often than not I'm working with text files anyways.